# NameError in Snakemake dryrun mode

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I am new to Snakemake and I am trying to develop some pipelines. I am encountering some problems when I use wildcards, trying to automate my bioinformatic analyses as much as possible. I run into troubles when the pipeline becomes more complex (as shown below). It looks like Snakemake does not resolve the wildcards correctly. During a dry run of the Snakefile, the wildcards values look correct in the executions of some rules. However, the same wildcards lead to an error in a different step(rule) of the pipeline, and I cannot figure out why. Below I provide the code and the output message of a dry run.

```
num=["327905-LR-41624_normal","327907-LR-41624_tumor"]
num_normal=["327905-LR-41624"]
num_tumor=["327907-LR-41624"]

path="/path/to/Snakemake/"
genome="/path/to/references_genome/Mus_musculus.GRCm38.dna_rm.toplevel.fa"

rule all:
    input:  
    expand("/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num_tum}_tumor_no_dupl_sort_RG_LB.bam",num_tum=num_tumor),
    expand("/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num_norm}_normal_no_dupl_sort_RG_LB.bam",num_norm=num_normal)
ruleorder: samtools_sort > remove_duplicates >  samtools_index #>     add_readgroup_tumor > add_readgroup_normal

rule trim_galore:
    input:
        r1="/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_R1.fastq",
        r2="/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_R2.fastq"
    output:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num }_R1_val_1.fq",
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num }_R2_val_2.fq"
    shell:
        "module load trim-galore/0.5.0 ; module load pypy/2.7-6.0.0 ; trim_galore  --output_dir /path/to/Snakemake/  --paired {input.r1} {input.r2}  "  

rule bwa_mem:
    input:
        R1="/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_R1_val_1.fq",
        R2="/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_R2_val_2.fq"
    output:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}.bam"
    shell:
        "module load samtools/default ; module load bwa/0.7.8 ; bwa mem  {genome}  {input.R1} {input.R2} | samtools view -h -b  > {output} "

rule samtools_sort:
    input:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}.bam"
    output:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_sort.bam"
    shell:
        "module load samtools/default ; samtools sort -n  -O BAM {input} > {output} "

rule remove_duplicates:
    input:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_sort.bam"
    output:
        outbam="/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_no_dupl_sort.bam",
        metrics="/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_dupl_metrics.txt"
    shell:
        "module load gatk/4.0.9.0 ; gatk MarkDuplicates -I {input}  -O {output.outbam} -M {output.metrics}  --REMOVE_DUPLICATES=true "

rule samtools_index:
    input:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_no_dupl_sort.bam"
    output:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_no_dupl_sort.bam.bai"
    shell:
        "module load samtools/default ; samtools index  {input} "

rule add_readgroup_normal:
    input:
    "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num_normal}_normal_no_dupl_sort.bam"
output:
    "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num_normal}_normal_no_dupl_sort_RG_LB.bam"
shell:
    "module load gatk/4.0.9.0 ;  gatk AddOrReplaceReadGroups   -PL Illumina -LB  { num_normal }   -PU  { num_normal }  -SM  NORMAL  -I  { input }    -O  {output} "

rule add_readgroup_tumor:
    input:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num_tumor}_tumor_no_dupl_sort.bam"
    output:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num_tumor}_tumor_no_dupl_sort_RG_LB.bam"
    shell:
        "module load gatk/4.0.9.0 ;  gatk AddOrReplaceReadGroups   -PL Illumina -LB  { num_tumor }   -PU  { num_tumor }  -SM  TUMOR     -I  { input }    -O  {output} "
```

When I test the Snakefile with the command:
    .local/bin/snakemake  -s Snakefile_pipeline  --dryrun

I get the following:

```
**Building DAG of jobs...**


**Job counts:**
    **count jobs
    1   add_readgroup_normal
    1   add_readgroup_tumor
    1   all
    2   bwa_mem
    2   remove_duplicates
    2   samtools_sort
    2   trim_galore
    11**

**[Mon Apr  8 16:14:27 2019]
rule trim_galore:
    input: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor_R1.fastq, /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor_R2.fastq
    output: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor_R1_val_1.fq, /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor_R2_val_2.fq
    jobid: 9
    wildcards: num=327907-LR-41624_tumor**


**[Mon Apr  8 16:14:27 2019]
rule trim_galore:
    input: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_R1.fastq, /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_R2.fastq
    output: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_R1_val_1.fq, /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_R2_val_2.fq
    jobid: 10
    wildcards: num=327905-LR-41624_normal**


**[Mon Apr  8 16:14:27 2019]
rule bwa_mem:
    input: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_R1_val_1.fq, /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_R2_val_2.fq
    output: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal.bam
    jobid: 8
    wildcards: num=327905-LR-41624_normal**


**[Mon Apr  8 16:14:27 2019]
rule bwa_mem:
    input: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor_R1_val_1.fq, /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor_R2_val_2.fq
    output: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor.bam
    jobid: 7
    wildcards: num=327907-LR-41624_tumor**


**[Mon Apr  8 16:14:27 2019]
rule samtools_sort:
    input: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor.bam
    output: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor_sort.bam
    jobid: 5
    wildcards: num=327907-LR-41624_tumor**


**[Mon Apr  8 16:14:27 2019]
rule samtools_sort:
    input: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal.bam
    output: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_sort.bam
    jobid: 6
    wildcards: num=327905-LR-41624_normal**


**[Mon Apr  8 16:14:27 2019]
rule remove_duplicates:
    input: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor_sort.bam
    output: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor_no_dupl_sort.bam, /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor_dupl_metrics.txt
    jobid: 3
    wildcards: num=327907-LR-41624_tumor**


**[Mon Apr  8 16:14:27 2019]
rule remove_duplicates:
    input: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_sort.bam
    output: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_no_dupl_sort.bam, /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_dupl_metrics.txt
    jobid: 4
    wildcards: num=327905-LR-41624_normal**


**[Mon Apr  8 16:14:27 2019]
rule add_readgroup_normal:
    input: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_no_dupl_sort.bam
    output: /path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_no_dupl_sort_RG_LB.bam
    jobid: 2
    wildcards: num_normal=327905-LR-41624**

**RuleException in line 93 of /home/l136n/Snakefile_mapping_snv_call_pipeline2:
NameError: The name ' num_normal ' is unknown in this context. Please make sure that you defined that variable. Also note that braces not used for variable access have to be escaped by repeating them, i.e. {{print $1}}**
```

I have googled the error but found little help. Also, I double checked the pipeline for any incosistency. What I expect as output is indicated in the rule "all".  The rules "add_readgroup_normal" and "add_readgroup_tumor" are supposed to take different subsets of input files, generated by the previous steps, which are run on all files. I wonder if the problem arises somehow because of this separation into 2 subsets. 
I repeat that I am quite new to Snakemake, so I might be missing something silly somewhere! Any help would be really appreciated, as I am completely stuck! 
Thank you so much in advance!

```
num=["327905-LR-41624_normal","327907-LR-41624_tumor"]
normal=["327905-LR-41624_normal"]
num_tumor=["327907-LR-41624_tumor"]

path="/path/to/Snakemake/"
genome="/icgc/dkfzlsdf/analysis/B210/references_genome/Mus_musculus.GRCm38.dna_rm.toplevel.fa"

rule all:
    input:  
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_R1_val_1.fq",
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_R2_val_2.fq",
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor_R1_val_1.fq",
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor_R2_val_2.fq",
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_no_dupl_sort.bam.bai",
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor_no_dupl_sort.bam.bai",
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_RG.bam"
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor_RG.bam"


rule trim_galore:
    input:
        r1="/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_R1.fastq",
        r2="/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_R2.fastq"
    output:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num }_R1_val_1.fq",
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num }_R2_val_2.fq"
    shell:
        "module load trim-galore/0.5.0 ; module load pypy/2.7-6.0.0 ; trim_galore  --output_dir /path/to/Snakemake/  --paired {input.r1} {input.r2}  "  

rule bwa_mem:
    input:
        R1="/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_R1_val_1.fq",
        R2="/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_R2_val_2.fq"
    output:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}.bam"
    shell:
        "module load samtools/default ; module load bwa/0.7.8 ; bwa mem  {genome}  {input.R1} {input.R2} | samtools view -h -b  > {output} "

rule samtools_sort:
    input:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}.bam"
    output:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_sort.bam"
    shell:
        "module load samtools/default ; samtools sort -n  -O BAM {input} > {output} "

rule remove_duplicates:
    input:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_sort.bam"
    output:
        outbam="/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_no_dupl_sort.bam",
        metrics="/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_dupl_metrics.txt"
    shell:
        "module load gatk/4.0.9.0 ; gatk MarkDuplicates -I {input}  -O {output.outbam} -M {output.metrics}  --REMOVE_DUPLICATES=true "

rule samtools_index:
    input:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_no_dupl_sort.bam"
    output:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_no_dupl_sort.bam.bai"
    shell:
        "module load samtools/default ; samtools index  {input} "

rule add_readgroup_normal:
    input:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{normal}_no_dupl_sort.bam"
    output:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{normal}_RG.bam"
    shell:
        "module load gatk/4.0.9.0 ;  gatk AddOrReplaceReadGroups   -PL Illumina -LB  { wildcards.normal }   -PU  { wildcards.normal }  -SM  NORMAL  -I  { input }    -O  {output} "

rule add_readgroup_tumor:
    input:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num}_no_dupl_sort.bam"
    output:
        "/path/to/Snakemake/AS-{num_,'.*tumor.*'}_RG.bam"
    shell:
        "module load gatk/4.0.9.0 ;  gatk AddOrReplaceReadGroups   -PL Illumina -LB  { wildcards.num }   -PU  { wildcards.num }  -SM  TUMOR     -I  { input }    -O  {output} "
```

Error:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 37 of /home/l136n/Snakefile_mapping_snv_call_pipeline2b1:
Missing input files for rule trim_galore:
/path/to/Luca/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_RG.bam/path/to/Luca/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor_RG_R1.fastq
/path/to/Snakemake/AS-327905-LR-41624_normal_RG.bam/path/to/Luca/Snakemake/AS-327907-LR-41624_tumor_RG_R2.fastq
```

Answer (score 2):

Wildcards are accessible in `shell` using syntax `{wilcards.var}`, not `{var}`. You have the latter in `rule add_readgroup_normal`.
[Source](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#wildcards).

Comment: Thanks a lot **JeeYem**!  I tried to fix and improve my code (I added to my original question). However I am running into different problems unfortunately. Now the error is "Missing input files" ...

Comment: Instead of working on all of the rules at once, I would suggest starting with one rule and then adding more rules once you have them working. Writing a medium/large pipeline and then debugging only in the end can easily lead to confusion.

Comment: I tried already. All works fine as long as I do not use wildcards in the shell command of "add_readgroup_normal". If I attempt to use { wildcards.var } it returns an error. It is really mysterious to me!

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would provide the solution, even if the post is a bit old now. The error was simply due to the presence of spaces inside "{ wildcards.var }".