# Snakemake NameError wildcards

Tags: pipeline, bioinformatics, snakemake

I have been trying to create my first Snakemake pipeline, but I have run into a NameError when running it.
Here is the code:

```
configfile: "../config/config.yaml"

LONGREADS = config["LONGREADS"]
LONGREAD_FILE_TYPE = config["LONGREAD_FILE_TYPE"]
SHORTREADS1 = config["SHORTREADS1"]
SHORTREADS2 = config["SHORTREADS2"]
PREFIX = config["PREFIX"]
REFERENCE = config["REFERENCE"]
OUTDIR = config["OUTDIR"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{outdir}/PycoQC/", outdir=OUTDIR)

if LONGREAD_FILE_TYPE.upper() == "FAST5":
    rule fast5_conversion:
        message:
            "Rule {rule} processing"
        group:
            "Read processing"
        output:
            directory("{outdir}/pod5/")
        threads: 32
        resources:
            mem_mb=30000,
            runtime=75
        conda:
            "envs/pod5.yaml"
        shell:
            "pod5 convert fast5 {LONGREADS}/*.fast5 {output} -t {threads}"

    rule basecalling:
        message:
            "Rule {rule} processing"
        group:
            "Read processing"
        input:
            rules.fast5_conversion.output
        output:
            directory("{outdir}/guppy_6_5_7_sup/")
        threads: 3
        resources:
            gpu=1,
            mem_mb=7500,
            runtime=4500
        container:
            "docker://genomicpariscentre/guppy:6.5.7"
        shell:
            "guppy_basecaller -i {input} -s {output} --device auto --compress_fastq --records_per_fastq 0 --config dna_r9.4.1_450bps_sup.cfg"

elif LONGREAD_FILE_TYPE.upper() == "POD5":
    rule basecalling:
        message:
            "Rule {rule} processing"
        group:
            "Read processing"
        output:
            directory("{outdir}/guppy_6_5_7_sup/")
        threads: 3
        resources:
            gpu=1,
            mem_mb=7500,
            runtime=4500
        container:
            "docker://genomicpariscentre/guppy:6.5.7"
        shell:
            "guppy_basecaller -i {LONGREADS} -s {output} --device auto --compress_fastq --records_per_fastq 0 --config dna_r9.4.1_450bps_sup.cfg"

else:
    rule basecalling:
        message:
            "Please provide a valid long read file type."
        group:
            "Read processing"
        output:
            directory("{outdir}/guppy_6_5_7_sup/")
        shell:
            "^C"

rule long_read_trimming:
    message:
        "Rule {rule} processing"
    group:
        "Read processing"
    input:
        rules.basecalling.output
    output:
        "{outdir}/porechop_abi/trimmed_reads.fastq"
    threads: 24
    resources:
        mem_mb=210000,
        runtime=300
    conda:
        "envs/porechop_abi.yaml"
    shell:
        "porechop_abi --ab_initio --threads {threads} -i {input} -o {output}"

rule short_read_trimming:
    message:
        "Rule {rule} processing"
    group:
        "Read processing"
    output:
        directory("{outdir}/trimmomatic/")
    threads: 24
    conda:
        "envs/trimmomatic.yaml"
    shell:
        "for f1 in {SHORTREADS1}/*_1.fq.gz do f2=${f1%%_1.fq.gz}_2.fq.gz trimmomatic PE -threads {threads} -phred33 $f1 $f2 {output}/lane1_forwared_paired_${f1##*/} {output}lane1_forward_unpaired_${f1##*/}.fq.gz {output}lane1_reverse_paired_${f2##*/}.fq.gz {output}lane1_reverse_unpaired_${f2##*/}.fq.gz ILLUMINACLIP:/home/WUR/hoger006/lustre_dir/Tools/mambaforge/envs/trimmomatic/share/trimmomatic/adapters/TruSeq3-PE.fa:2:30:10 LEADING:3 TRAILING:3 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:15 MINLEN:36 done"

rule pycoqc:
    message:
        "Rule {rule} processing"
    group:
        "Quality control"
    input:
        rules.basecalling.output
    output:
        directory("{outdir}/PycoQC/")
    threads: 5
    resources:
        mem_mb=3500,
        runtime=15
    conda:
        "envs/pycoqc.yaml"
    shell:
        "pycoQC -f {input}/sequencing_summary.txt -o {output}output.html"
```

And here is the error:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cluster nodes: 10
Job stats:
job                 count    min threads    max threads
----------------  -------  -------------  -------------
all                     1              1              1
basecalling             1              3              3
fast5_conversion        1             32             32
pycoqc                  1              5              5
total                   4              1             32

Select jobs to execute...
[Tue Jul  4 13:37:46 2023]

group job Read processing (jobs in lexicogr. order):

    [Tue Jul  4 13:37:46 2023]
    Job 2: Rule basecalling processing
    Reason: Missing output files: ../results/guppy_6_5_7_sup; Input files updated by another job: ../results/pod5


    [Tue Jul  4 13:37:46 2023]
    Job 3: Rule fast5_conversion processing
    Reason: Missing output files: ../results/pod5

WorkflowError:
NameError with group job aa08bb21-d8a7-5a54-b420-1d366d760cbe: The name 'outdir' is unknown in this context. Did you mean 'wildcards.outdir'?
```

I have seen similar errors, such as [NameError in Snakemake dryrun mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55576386/nameerror-in-snakemake-dryrun-mode), but I am not sure how to implement this in my case, like I mentioned I am fairly new at this. Thanks in advance for any help!